# Eject device requires root rassword after automount

Tags: linux, bash, automount

I configured automount utility to mount my usb flash drive when it's plugged. It also sets my current user as owner of mountpoint, but when I'm trying to ejevt flash drive, I'm prompted a passsword.

My automount.conf

```
ENABLED=1
MOUNTPOINTS="/media/usb0 /media/usb1 /media/usb2 /media/usb3
             /media/usb4 /media/usb5 /media/usb6 /media/usb7"
FILESYSTEMS="vfat ext2 ext3 ext4 hfsplus"
MOUNTOPTIONS="noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,uid=user,gid=user"
FS_MOUNTOPTIONS=""
VERBOSE=no
```

How can I get rid of this password prompt?